# Redirecting a call using Asterisk.NET

Tags: c#, sip, voip, asterisk, asteriskami

I am trying to redirect a call using Asterisk.NET Library. But it doesn't work as I expected.
For Eg: If A calls B and I transfer it to C, Source A will be disconnected, and B and C will be connected. This is my code snippet for transferring the call.

```
            RedirectAction ra = new RedirectAction(sip_channel_of_B, "internal", 1000 , 1);
            ManagerResponse rr = manager.SendAction(ra);
```

Comment: Sounds like it's working properly. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I solved it myself,,,, The problem was, I was using the destination channel.... It should be Source channel (CHannel of A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by changing the channel.
RedirectAction expects the source channel; not the destination channel....

Comment: Anywhere it can be used naa ? 
It's not an event. It's action sending to the Manager instance.